# Richcopy: How do I enable file exclusions?

Tags: utilities

I'm trying to use Rich Copy to copy log files that are older than 60 days from a directory.  Whenever I go in and set the exclusion rules, Rich copy seems to ignore them and just copies everything.  Is there something that I'm doing wrong.  Bonus question: Does Terracopy work better for this type of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used RichCopy before as I tend to use RoboCopy from the command line for this type of thing.

> Robocopy /MINAGE:60

would basically only copy stuff older than 60 days. Lots more options are available in this rediculously usefull tool.

Alternatively, if its a one off and the files are in one folder you could order the folder by date (created / modified) and copy the ones older than 6 months.

Another alternative if its a one of, and the files are spread across directories etc would be to use the windows search tool and search for *.log older than 60 days etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you are using the latest copy of RichCopy, the current copy (as of today) is 4.0.217

Similar problems were reported in older versions.